# How to update header component after login

Tags: angular, authentication, service, components, dashboard

In my dashboard application I have a service that receive data from server and save it on sessionStorage after user login.
How to update a html select on header component after user logged in?

thanks.

Comment: Hi, please look up the how to ask questions guide. Your question is missing a lot and it will be hard for others to help. Please add what you have tried so far, some code or the architecture of your application. This seems like a common pattern so please try and search more for some answers before asking.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i need to know best practice only